# CakePHP doesn't load model

Tags: cakephp, model

I'm new to cakePhp development. I've stuck on following problem:
I've made few models, controllers and views - it works great. The problem is that after production, I have to made new table(**Transactionaltemp** table and corresponding model and controller ) in the db that logically is "connected" to other tables, but technically does not needs to - for ex. it holds temporary info on user_id, time, ip and similar. So, other tables doesn't need to be directly connected to that.
The **problem** is when I try (in some other controller than `transactionaltemps_controller`):

```
$this->loadModel('Transactionaltemp');
```

I get error - the model is not found (it is true because the model **is missing** in the cache). Interesting enough `transactionaltempls_controller` is in the cache (in the `cake_controllers_list` file).
I tried following stuff to resolve the problem:

1. clear cache
2. disable cache
3. tried using `uses={..}` code in the controller that I would like to use `mymodels_controller`
4. tried using `init('Transactionaltemp')`

with no success. Here is corresponding code:
The model:

```
<?php 
class Transactionaltemp extends AppModel
{
   var $name = 'Transactionaltemp';
   function beforeSave() {
    return true;
   }
}
?>
```

The controller:

```
<?php
 class TransactionaltempsController extends AppController
 {
    var $name = 'Transactionaltemps';
    var $scaffold;

 }
 ?>
```

I'll very grateful to any help!!!

Comment: What is the name of the file in which you have defined your model?

Comment: Can you access the model from its own controller (Transactionaltemps)?

Comment: Yes, I can access the model from its own controller. Name of the file in which I have defined my model is same as model's class name - transactionaltemp.php

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code to show some context around how you are using loadModel(). The syntax for uses, BTW, is var $uses=array('ModelOne','ModelTwo'); not as you have written above. If you do use $uses, the host model must be first in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
App:Import('Model','Transactionaltemp');
$this->Transactionaltemp= new Transactionaltemp;
```

I hope this may work

Comment: It works for me but a bit fixing;
(App:Import to App::Import)

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to a table name with different name than your model, you must specify the table name in it:

```
<?php 
class Transactionaltemp extends AppModel
{
   var $uses = 'Transactional';
   var $name = 'Transactionaltemp';
   function beforeSave() {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But that's not the case - I'm using apsolutely the same name. (confused)

Comment: Hhhmm.. is very strange.. check that you have used names following the CakePHP naming conventions.. http://book.cakephp.org/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions if you done that.. I don't know what is happening, I'm sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
App::Import('Model', 'YourModelName');
```

in your controller (or where you want).